# Ubuntu wont load after installing SLiM

Tags: login, login-screen, display-manager, slim

A few moments ago I decided to give the SLiM display manager a go, and I installed it with apt, then I restarted my PC and it got stuck at the loading page with the ubuntu logo and the six loading dots under it.

Right now Im running my installation DVD as a LiveCD. My version of Ubuntu is 13.10, and Id been using the default Unity LightDM up until now.

Any help trying to fix this or any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: press F2 when you see the boot logo for ubuntu with the dots to see a verbose output to give you a better idea on what's going on